Usin side input to reset a state variable in a ptransform
I have a situation like below
> `> `PCollection<KV<Row,Long>> stream_full_snapshot = ...; //this will bring in full sync inventory snapshot every day at 12:00 AM i.e. fixed window size of 24 hours, with allowed lateness of 2 hours, firing as soon first element arrives in pane

PCollection<KV<Row,Long>> stream_cycle_count = ...; //this will bring in cycle count of items from warehouse or store. When cycle count arrives, current stock position will be overwritten,

PCollection<KV<Row,Long>> stream_transactions = ...; // this will bring in store transactions from POS, items sold in store will be deducted frm current stock position``

I want to process stream_transaction as below
stream_transactions.apply (ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<Row,Long>, KV<Row,Long>>(){

//define state variable called availability

//declare state variable called availability
//declare state variable called availability_is_read


   //1. if stream_cycle_count is not null OR stream_full_snapshot is not null 
   //2. initialize availability == set latest of stream_full_snapshot or stream_full_snapshot
   //3. initialize availability_is_read as false
     
   
processElement

//1. get availability, 
//2. if availability is null, return KV<Row, 0L> // there is no point of availability if stock position it self is null
//3. If availability is not null, calculate new availability as current_availability-input.getValue()
//4. set new availability in state. set availability_is_read as true.
//5. return KV<Row, new_availability>
//6.  every 5s, read all availability where  availability_is_read is false.
//7.  for every such availability -- return PCollection<KV<Row, Long(initial availability as set during initialization)>> 


}).withsideInputs(stream_cycle_count,stream_full_snapshot))


As you can see, I am trying to do things which will not work with regular state and timer.
Any suggestions will be highly appreciated!!
I was trying to use state and timers but apparently, I can not use multiple side input to control the state and timersyour text
